# js получить данные с другого сайта

Tags: javascript

нужно сделать плагин, который берет за основу погоду в определенном городе. Есть ли какая нибудь функция, которая позволяет заглядывать на чужой сайт и проверять какую либо переменную?

Полного решения не нужно, просто дайте направление

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть два варианта:

1. Найти сайт погоды, который предоставляет API и работать через него
2. Делать на сервере запрос к чужому сайту, парсить с него данные и отправлять на клиент

Как вариант смотрите:

- https://www.gismeteo.ru/api/
- https://tech.yandex.ru/weather/

Answer (score 1):

Если сайт поддерживает кроссдомменные запросы - то можно использовать ajax.
Если нет, то только с сервера - см. CURL etc.